# Linq2Sql static Datacontext in DAL

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql, data-access-layer, datacontext

I am new to Linq to sql. And my question is simple.

Is it a good idea to have DataContext as public static member in DAL to act as singleton?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I generally try to group functionality together for a Data Access class and make that class IDisposable.
Then you Create your DataContext in your constructor and in your dispose method you run your .dispose() call on the DataContext.

So then when you need something from that class you can wrap it in a using statement, and make a bunch of calls all using the same DataContext.

It's pretty much the same effect as using a Static DataContext, but means you don't forget to close down the connection, and it seems a bit more OO than making things static.

```
    public class MyDataAccessClass: IDisposable
    {
      private readonly DbDataContext _dbContext;

      public MyDataAccessClass()
      {
          _dbContext = new DbDataContext ();
      }

      public void Dispose()
      {
        _dbContext.Dispose();
      }

      public List<CoolData> GetStuff()
      {
           var d = _dbContext.CallStuff();
           return d;
      }
    }
```

Then in your class

```
   using(var d = new MyDataAccessClass())
   {
         //Make lots of calls to different methods of d here and you'll reuse your DataContext
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

It is not really *good idea* to keep `DataContext` as singleton, for small application, you might not see any consequences, but if your web application which has many users to access, it will lead to *memory leak*. Why?

`DataContext` basically implements *Unit Of Work* behind the scene which has *internal cache* inside to track changes of entities and avoid round trip to database in one business transaction. Keeping `DataContext` for long time as static, it means internal cache will be increasing for the time being and is not released properly.

`DataContext` should be kept in one business transaction and release as soon as possible. Best practice for web application is to keep `DataContext` as per request. You are also able to make use of IoC Container, most of IoC Container support this.

Answer (score 2):

I have also experienced one thing while using shared datacontext in DAL. Suppose there are two users A and B. If User A starts and transaction then user B can commit changes made by user A which is a side effect of using static DataContext.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to read about **'unit of work'** pattern. I.e. http://stuartharris4.blogspot.com/2008/06/working-together-linq-to-sql.html

Answer (score 1):

You most definitely should not have a static `DataContext` in a multi-threaded application such as ASP.NET.  [The MSDN documentation for DataContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.aspx) states that:

> Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

Comment: I read this link dude. That's beautiful and very informative. Thanks for sharing. :)